# Criar array buscando mês atual

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou criando uma lista de alunos aniversariantes do mês, utilizando php e mysqli.

Não estou conseguindo carregar apenas os alunos aniversariantes do mês atual,consegui apenas no banco de dados, usando a função;

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Que me retorna corretamente os alunos do mês atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já no PHP carrega todos os alunos!*

Código utilizado:

```
$students = $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
foreach ($students as $row):
```

Minha dificuldade é criar o array buscando somente os alunos aniversariantes do mês do campo Birthday da tabela student.

Valor atual do array:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual valor das arrays?

Comment: Estou utilizando <?php echo date('d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-",$row['birthday']))); ?> para mostrar somente o dia.

Comment: o Array está carregando todos os alunos! Vou add uma imagem.

Comment: @PedroPaulo não seria mais fácil você criar uma **View** no banco e depois só exibir o resultado na página ?

Comment: Data é um `varchar` no banco?

Comment: @rray, isso mesmo.

Comment: Eu tenho sugestão meio complicado: `$test = explode("/", $row["birthday"]); if (test[1] == "07") {echo row["birthday"]}
` Você poderia validar se fosse do mês atual no php.

Comment: Pode fazer a mesma consulta veja => https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html .

Comment: @rray! Boa, agora vou ver se consigo criar o row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$where = "MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW())";
$this->db->where($where);
$students = $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
foreach ($students as $row):
```

Comment: Você testou antes?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigado @Victor Carnaval.

Comment: Obrigado também @rray! Pelo link compartilhado, vou dar uma estudada.

Comment: Dê nada! Fico feliz em ajudá-lo!